# Animation Nodes: derivate and antiderivate

Tags: animation-nodes

I would like to know if there is a method to derivate or antiderivate a function in animation nodes.

Thank's

Comment: Hello, could you elaborate a bit more on the process you are looking for ?

Comment: For example. I have the function (90*sin(frame))/frame and I want to antiderivate it